# Google Dialogflow session ending while navigating the site

Tags: session, chat, dialogflow-es

Looking to solve Dialogflow flow user session resets per new page on the same site and their progress isn't saved as the user continues the conversation. Read similar requests and wondering that this is something configurable on our end or Dialogflow doesn't have this feature of continuous user interaction on one domain in between different pages?

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger

Recommended article wasn't unfortunately helpful, but I hope I can find a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining user session continuity across different pages of the same site in Dialogflow ES can indeed be achieved by persisting the session ID. The Dialogflow ES version uses session IDs to identify and maintain the state of a conversation with a user.

Since you are using Dialogflow Messenger, you can control the session ID through the `df-messenger` HTML tag. By reusing the same session ID value across different pages on your site, you can maintain the continuity of the conversation.

Here's how you can implement it:

1. [**Generate and Store a Unique Session ID**](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api#sessions): When a user starts a conversation, generate a unique session ID and store it in the user's session storage or a cookie. This ID should be unique to the user but consistent across the pages.
2. [**Set the Session ID in the `df-messenger` Tag**](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#html-customize): Use the stored session ID when initializing the `df-messenger` tag on each page. You can set the `session-id` attribute to the stored session ID value. For example:

   ```html
   <df-messenger
     intent="WELCOME"
     chat-title="Your Chat Title"
     agent-id="your-agent-id"
     language-code="en"
     session-id="your-stored-session-id">
   </df-messenger>
   ```

Additionally, if you have an existing method to maintain a unique session ID for user identification, you can use that. For instance, in my implementation, session IDs are generated and managed server-side.